# SQL - Alinhar Valores das Colunas para Direita

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se por meio de uma setença SQL existe alguma possiblidiade de alinhar os valores das colunas para a direita. Segue um exemplo abaixo que consigo fazer via C#, mas queria fazer o alinhamento somente via T-SQL:

Código em C# que funciona:

```
result = string.Format("{0,16}{1,8}{2,4}{3,6}{4,15}{5,15}{6,16}",
                       reader["Coluna1"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna2"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna3"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna4"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna5"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna6"].ToString(),
                       reader["Coluna7"].ToString());
```

Resultado da variável "result":
211582060520130004059:30           0,00           0.00           0,00N

Comment: O SQL não tem nada a ver com isso, aqui funciona. O SQL é para pegar dados, não para formatar dados. Não faça gambiarras, use a ferramenta cverta para o problema. Como curiosidade seu código poderia ser muito mais simples: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A8JDgi. Mandei imprimir para você ver, mas poderia ter guardado em variável como fez, dá no mesmo, só trocar o `WriteLine()` pela atribuição. E claro o `x` por cada item do `reader`, sem `.ToString()`.

Comment: Essas são as funções disponíveis em SQL.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp  E, claro, você pode criar as suas proprias.